# Jackson ObjectMapper Exception: Invalid type definition for type "Person"

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I get this Exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type 'main.Person': Failed to construct BeanSerializer for [simple type, class main.Person]: (java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException) Unable to make public java.lang.String main.Person.getFirstname() accessible: module JsonTest does not "exports main" to module com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

I'm new to Jackson and I don't understand whats wrong.
I couldn't find anything in the web, so maybe you can help me.

My Code is following:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int id;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int id) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.id=id;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
            return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
           this.firstname = firstname;
    }
     public String getLastname() {
            return this.lastname;
     }

    public void setLastname(String firstname) {
           this.lastname = firstname;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        File file = new File("Desktop/test.json");
        
        Person per = new Person("peter","lol",2);
        objectMapper.writeValue(file, per);
    }
}
```

Nothing special but still not working :(
I imported the Jackson .jar Libraries to my Eclipse java project, maybe thats an information you need.

Regards

Comment: It looks like you're using the module-system of java. So you have to export your package where the person class is in. Otherwise Jackson can't access it.

Comment: Thanks that was the Issue!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is I needed to export my package in the module

```
module JacksonTest {
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    exports myPackage; // <--- Solution
}
```